# Obtain constant from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I need to extract constant C[1] from expression which I get when solve equation.
i.e.

```
DSolve[y'[x]==1/(2x),y[x],x]
```

In result Mathematica gives me this one

```
y[x]->C[1]+1/2 Log[x]
```

But I want something like this

```
C[1]=x Exp[-2y]
```

I'll try to use DSolve.Constant[] (sound like exactly what I want, but isn't working unfortunately)
Please, help me.

Comment: So, transform the rule to an equation and `Solve` it. You can transform it using the prediction interface of *Mathematica*

Comment: @Sektor Thanks. I did it.
    sol = DSolveValue[y'[x] - 1/(2x) == 0, y[x], x]
    Solve[y[x] == sol, C[1]]

Comment: Or: Solve[Keys[#] == Values[#] &[DSolve[y'[x] == 1/(2 x), y[x], x]], C[1]]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
       expr1 = y[x] -> C[1] + 1/2 Log[x]

  (*   y[x] -> C[1] + Log[x]/2   *)

    expr2 = expr1[[2]] == y

  (*    C[1] + Log[x]/2 == y  *)

    expr3 = Map[Subtract[#, Log[x]/2] &, expr2]

    (*  C[1] == y - Log[x]/2  *)


        Map[Exp, expr3] /. E^C[1] -> C2

     (*     C2 == E^y/Sqrt[x]    *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This only answers the question in this specific case. Which the OP has already done by hand.

Comment: @Myridium 6  Of course. But this is also the way in a more complex case, and no general solution at all.

Comment: @PilgrimViis demonstrated a general solution.

Comment: @ Myridium No, he did not. It is just an illusion. In a general case equation for `C[1] ` may be a transcendental one, `Solve ` returning nothing in that case. But the point is that one in reality needs no such general solution, but a reasonable case by case consideration.